# Error: Data too long for column 'imagen' at row 1 with column 'MEDIUMBLOB' in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm storing images ranging from 1MB and maximum 7mb in a MySQL database. To do this I created a table with a field *MEDIUMBLOB* type having a capacity of *16,777,215 bytes* which is the same 16mb. When I save images up to 2.2MB it is perfectly stored, but when saving images larger but not exceeding the 7mb get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: 
Data too long for column 'imagen' at row 1
```

This is the definition of the image field in my entity image:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "Imagen")
@XmlRootElement
public class Imagen implements Serializable {
    // otros campos
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "imagen", columnDefinition = "mediumblob")
    private byte[] imagen;

   // getters and setters
}
```

My repository class:

```
public interface ImagenRepository extends BaseRepository<Imagen, Integer> {

    // other query operations

}
```

Base class repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>, Finder<T>, Counter {

    public T save(T save);

    public void delete(ID id);

    public void delete(T entity);

    public Optional<T> findOne(ID id);

}
```

Image table:

```
CREATE TABLE Imagen (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- Otros campos
    imagen MEDIUMBLOB,
    type VARCHAR(10) COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

For query operations and persistence use spring-data-jpa.

I do not understand why not save images of more than 2.2MB, please help

Answer (score 0):

You might need to increase your server settings for `innodb_log_file_size` in my.cnf. Then restart MySQL.

Comment: I had already increased to 160 MB, because I understood that it should be 10 times the size of the column (16x10 = 160). I am right?